# How to display error Modal using jQuery for Failed condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, bootstrap-modal

When user submit a YES button, JS will get a data from Backend using API (JSON Data). But I am trying to simulate an error by make the URL false. Unfortunately the error Modal does not appear in my HTML page, the dataTables just keep loading. Should anyone read my JS below and comment if the structure is true or not.

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="alert2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content bg-danger text-white">
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <h3 class="text-white mb-15">ERROR</h3>
                <span>Upload Failed</span>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
//By default to view DataTables for Upload Page
$("#myTable").DataTable({
    "ajax": { 
    "url": "X.X.X.X/api/managefile",
    "type": "POST"
   },

    "columns": 
        [
            { "data": "filename", "className": "text-center" },
            { "data": "date", "className": "text-center" },
            { "data": "uploader", "className": "text-center" },                 
        ]
    });

$(document).ready(function() {   

    $("#myTable").change(function() {                   
        console.log($("#myTable").val());

        if ($("#myTable").val() == "") {
            $("#btnSubmit").attr('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            $("#btnSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });

     // This will run when user click YES button
    $("#btnYes").on("click",function(){

        $("#myTable").DataTable( {                      
            processing: true,
            crossDomain: true,      //Is this 
            language: 
                    {          
                    "loadingRecords": "<img src='images/loading.gif' />"
                    },                  
            dom: 'Bfltip',
            buttons: [                          
                {
                    className: 'btn-export',
                    extend:    'csvHtml5',
                    text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>',
                    titleAttr: 'CSV'
                }
                      ],                        
            destroy: true,
            ajax: { 
                url: "result/managefiles.json",
                type: "POST"
                },
            columns: [
                { data: "filename", "className": "text-center" },
                { data: "date", "className": "text-center" },
                { data: "uploader", "className": "text-center" },
                     ],
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);              
                },
                error: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#alert2').modal('show');
                }                       

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `error:` function in your Ajax call will trigger only if the server (API) returned an HTTP error code.

so there would be two ways to implement this, either return an HTTP error from the server, either return a "success" key in your JSON response and based on that "success" entry decide how to proceed.

**JSON Response**
//it would be something like this

```
{
    "success": "done" or "error"
    "data": //data you want to return
}
```

**AJAX callback**

```
success: function(data){
    if (data.success === "error")
         //show modal 
    else if (data.success == "success")
        //proceed           
}
```

Comment: understood. so need JSON to response status whether OK or NOT. Is there have any other alternative beside get JSON response?

Comment: No I don't think so. as I said error: will trigger only in case of HTTP error returned by the server. otherwise (if the request was HTTP successful) there should be a way to inform client-side app how to proceed. and it should be done in the JSON response.